# IIS request timeout is set to 60 minutes but scripts timeout after a couple of minutes

Tags: iis, asp-classic, web-config, iis-7.5

I have a site running on windows 2008 R2 IIS 7.5.
I am having trouble with script timeouts and can't seem to find the correct setting to fix this.

We run some scripts that pull data from an SQL server via Classic ASP. for some data heavy scripts we are finding we get timeouts after just a few minutes.

I have the Connection Time-out (Seconds) set to 3600
and the Script Time-out (in ASP > Limits Properties set to 02:00:00

So I can't work out why timeouts occur after just a couple of minutes.

Have I missed another setting somewhere?

[image][image]

Comment: Try resetting the IIS values back to their defaults (`Connection Time-Out (seconds): 120`, `Script Time-Out: 00:01:30`) and in your `.ASP` page set `Server.ScriptTimeout = x seconds`. I sometime pull and format a lot of data from MySQL, I've had scripts run for days without timing-out by adjusting the `Server.ScriptTimeout` value. However, if the error you're getting is a SQL error then the problem is with your SQL time-out settings, not ASP.

Comment: I will try that. The problem is definitely not sql related though, it’s definitely a timeout due the asp config

Comment: Have you set idle time-out in the application pool? In addition, I also found [AspScriptTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524831(v=vs.90)#remarks)(A default ScriptTimeout can be set for a Web service or Web server by using the AspScriptTimeout metabase property. The ScriptTimeout property cannot be set to a value less than that specified in the metabase), but I did not find this property setting in my iis (I use iis10).

Comment: @samwu hi it's not asp.net so i don't believe an application pool is applicable here

Comment: @Adam i've done as you suggested, however you can't set the Script Time-out to 00:01:30, the default seems to be 00:30:00

i then added the code to the page but set it to 1 second to see if it would timeout (to see if that code worked), but it carried on regardless.

Comment: If you are still having problems with the session timing out, I suspect I know the answer.  Have you changed your Application Pool settings in IIS? 
 By default, IIS wants to use .NET settings.  

On the .NET CLR settings change it to "No Managed Code"
Set Managed Pipleline mode to Classic.

Side note - if this does fix it, mark as answer, because I had this problem and asked before and didn't get help, so this question/answer can be helpful to others if enough votes indicate this is the actual solution.

Comment: @chenks did you have a change to try my solution yet?  I had the identical problem you had, no amount of code would fix it, I got 5 minutes or so and sometimes it would go an hour, it would just not keep the session.  Then after determining it was IIS settings versus the code, I came up with the solution above.  Please just let me know if you tried this yet, thanks!

Comment: If you have JOINED tables get rid of that idea and isolate before requesting what you want... much faster,. If you are using an Access database upgrade to MS-SQL.